How many integer solutions satisfy $x^2+y^2\leq 20$?
I'm trying to find how many integer pairs $(x, y)$ satisfy the inequality $x^2+y^2\leq 20$ . I know this represents a circle with radius $\sqrt{20}\approx 4.47$, and I'm interested in counting the number of lattice points (integer coordinates) within or on this circle.
Is there a formula or method for counting the number of integer solutions to such inequalities? I've manually calculated that there are 69 such pairs, but I wonder if there's a general approach or known result for this type of problem, especially as the radius increases.
Any insights or references would be greatly appreciated!
$x^2+y^2\leq 20\ \ \ \ x, y \in \mathbb{Z}$

The answer is approximately $\pi r^2=20\pi$

This is Gauss's circle problem, more info on wiki.

$20\pi \approx 62$ estimates area, but the count is 69 due to boundary points. Any formulas for that?

$1+4(20-\lfloor20/3\rfloor+4-\lfloor20/7\rfloor+\lfloor20/9\rfloor-\lfloor20/11\rfloor+\lfloor20/13\rfloor-\lfloor20/15\rfloor+\lfloor20/17\rfloor-\lfloor20/19\rfloor)=69$

Another reference:   An Illustrated Theory of Numbers p. 106

My comment is a formula for you in the special case of $20$ on the right side. In general it's $1+4\sum_{k=0}^\infty(-1)^{k}\left\lfloor \frac{M}{2k+1}\right\rfloor$. The sum is finite for any $M$ because eventually the terms are all 0.

See OEIS sequence A057655 and formulas, links and references there.

This problem is the Gauss circle problem, for which the solution is $$N(r)=1+4\sum_{i=0}^\infty\left(\left\lfloor\frac{r^2}{4i+1}\right\rfloor-\left\lfloor\frac{r^2}{4i+3}\right\rfloor\right)$$
Note that even though it's an infinite sum, as soon as $i$ is large enough for the denominators to be greater than $r^2$, the floor function means all subsequent terms are $0$, so the value is finite.
For $r^2=20$:
$$N(\sqrt{20})=1+4\left(\left\lfloor\frac{20}{1}\right\rfloor-\left\lfloor\frac{20}{3}\right\rfloor+\left\lfloor\frac{20}{5}\right\rfloor-\left\lfloor\frac{20}{7}\right\rfloor+\left\lfloor\frac{20}{9}\right\rfloor-\left\lfloor\frac{20}{11}\right\rfloor+\left\lfloor\frac{20}{13}\right\rfloor-\left\lfloor\frac{20}{15}\right\rfloor+\left\lfloor\frac{20}{17}\right\rfloor-\left\lfloor\frac{20}{19}\right\rfloor+\left\lfloor\frac{20}{21}\right\rfloor+\dots\right)\\=1+4\left(20-6+4-2+2-1+1-1+1-1+0+\dots\right)\\=69$$

Uhhh, I'm not sure why my align environment isn't working
